# How to add conditionally a `Button` to a `Toolbar` `Form` `Component`?

Tags: codenameone

I have created a `Form` that is set to function as the `Toolbar` `Component` of a mobile application that I am working on.
I want to add a `Button` to it conditionally, depending on which `Form` screen is the `Toolbar` being added to.
I have tried the following but does not work:
`if(aForm.getTitle().equals("Target Form Screen's Title"))`
`aForm` is the `Form` to which the `Toolbar` is currently being added to. It is supposed to trigger the conditional when the `Form` title matches the target `Form` screen.

Comment: There are several ways how can you achieve it. 
Is your form the same in both cases, and the button is only difference?

Comment: @fnklstn Imagine a game interface where if a condition is achieved, then we exit to a final screen with the results. Only then, I want the "Settings" `Toolbar` `Form` to also add a `Button` to navigate to the initial "Home" screen. What would be a good term to use in the conditional statement's check?

Comment: You can set a Preference. For example,  if a condition is achieved, do `Preferences.set("LevelCompleted", true);`. Then check `if(Preferences.get("LevelCompleted", false)){//add your new button}`

Comment: You @fnklstn make a valid suggestion. However, from my point of view it adds a little bit more complexity than the one suggested by Shai below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare to the title in this way and it could work but generally it's a good practice to separate the UI and specific strings from the state. So you should have a separate class that controls the application state and decides what should be added.

If you need some state within the UI you can use `putClientProperty` and `getClientProperty`.

Comment: I will give it a try @Shai. It seems simple enough to implement.
PS. I am aware of the separation of concerns. I am trying to implement it.